# Sails.js - How to change a node.js module used by sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to write my own ejs-locals node module, but I also want that sails use mine and I don't want to change the sails `packages.json`.

How can I load, after sails loaded its `ejs-locals` module, my own module to override it?

If there is a proper way to do this kind of stuff, I would like to know :)
Thanks.

I tried to find the answer on the official documentation there: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/extending-sails

But there is nothing about that.

---

**Edit:**

I tried to use the `fn` attribute in the `config/views.js` but it doesn't work as expected, I've made an example here: https://github.com/Vadorequest/sails-custom-ejs-locals

---

**Final edit:**

It works fine with the solution proposed as accepted answer, just make sure to disable the `layout` or it will mess up your configuration. `layout: false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigth config is:

```
view: {
    engine: {
       ext: 'ejs',
       fn: yourfunction
   },
   // need to disabe sails.js default partials feature for dont auto load sails ejs-locals
   partial: false
}
```

Comment: I have tried and updated my experiment but it still doesn't work. https://github.com/Vadorequest/sails-custom-ejs-locals

Comment: Check this pull request ... https://github.com/Vadorequest/sails-custom-ejs-locals/pull/1 this will solve the problem

Comment: You're right, it does work. I understand that because `layout` is set to true then Sails load `ejs-locals` itself, because it's assuming we use ejs. But this is wrong. There is something to change is the core here, it should load our `fn` instead, if exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure you view engine in config/views.js file.

```
...

ext : 'ejs',
fn: require('ejs-locals')

...
```

Comment: This is using sails 0.9? I believe it's 0.10. Maybe I'll need to upgrade before to try it.

Comment: I tested this config with one .hbs engine and sails 0.10 but i dont know if works with sails 0.9
The views config logic is in: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/views/configure.js

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect in `0.9`, I tried `fn: "test"`to trigger an error and it works, so I guess that's new in 0.10. Thanks for hint.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, and if it does I'm not sure how to check it.

Comment: It doesn't work, sails is still using his own `ejs-locals`. A temporary solution was to replace the `node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals` by my own and it worked fine. I just don't like it at all.

Comment: I have just created an example of the issue, proving that the `fn` stuff doesn't work: https://github.com/Vadorequest/sails-custom-ejs-locals

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm shrinkwrap. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

Then edit `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and in the sails section, point ejs or ejs-lorals to your version